# ¿Conque propiedad un control se puede adaptar al tamaño del control que lo contiene?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wpf, xaml

Estoy trabajando con WPF, Visual Studio 2015
Tengo un problema en un tabItem de un TabControl, el problema radica que no se logran ver todos los controles que contiene el tabItem. Cuando he trabajado en Windows Forms he usado la propiedad `Dock = Fill`

El código XAML que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tabControlPrueba">
        <TabItem Header="Lista" Name="tabItemLista">
            <Canvas>
                <Label x:Name="label1" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="29">Nombre:</Label>
                <Label x:Name="label2" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="60">Dirección</Label>
            </Canvas>

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Datos">

        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Se ve la siguiente manera.
[image: TabControl]

Como pueden ver solo se ve el label del Nombre, y no el de la dirección.

Comment: porque cambiaste el grid que viene por un canvas?

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi,no uses canvas salvo en casos muy necesarios. Hay contenedores capaces de ajustar sus elementos de manera perfecta a partes iguales o con porcentajes.

Comment: @gbianchi Si tiene el Grid fíjate esta arriba.

Comment: @Pikoh logre solucionarlo cambiando el Canvas por un StackPanel

Comment: @gbianchi tiene el grid,pero dentro del tab tenía un canvas. Efectivamente,un stackpanel es una buena solucion.

Comment: Preguntaba por el grid q te pone automaticamente cuando tiras el tab al form. Con el stack panel se te va a cpmplicar hacer filas y columnas...

Comment: Oh, probare con el Grid, gracias @gbianchi